# Conversion of bytes to text

Tags: excel, function, automation, formula

I'm currently doing something for my convenience converting strings of numbers and characters to its corresponding values. Lets say i have the string

```
"712031ABCD        N             1"
```

Each byte corresponds to a value which I like to automate in Excel. I already did the function =LEFT(a1,1) to get the first byte of the string, and =mid(a1,2,1) for the 2nd byte and so on in another column.

All i need to do is to convert the value that populated from =left(a1,1) with let's say APPLE if it is with value of 7. Orange if its with a value of 8 and so on. And same is applicable with other bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the address formula with a conversion table made of cells (for example all cells in the H column contain the values for the byte contents of the bytes) and use the byte obtained by the left/mid formulas to reference it.

```
    H
7   Apple
8   Orange


Your cell: =address(left(a1,1),8)
```

8 is for the H column that I chose at random to hold the conversion table.

Comment: Hi, I think I find the right function to use. But there is still a problem to it. So I am using VLOOKUP and made a conversion table. All I need to do is reference the conversion table so that it looks for the value corresponding to the byte that populated the other column. But when I use the function =left(a1,1) in one column and reference it with the VLOOKUP, even the conditon is true, it returns the value N/A. And if I re-enter the value by typing, it gives the right value. What should I do?

Comment: VLOOKUP is used to find the location of a value, you're looking to set a value based on another... I really think that ADDRESS is the way to go, unless I misunderstood you.

Comment: @DavidKohen, you're statement about VLOOKUP is incorrect. It is used to find a value, not it's location. Perhaps you are thinking of MATCH.

Comment: @user1974571 - LEFT function always returns a text value (even when it looks like a number) so your VLOOKUP doesn't work because a number 2 doesn't match a text value "2" - when you make your lookup table insert the numeric values with a preceding apostrophe - e.g. '2 and they will be treated as text

Comment: @user1974571, `VLOOKUP` is the way to go. The different results you're seeing are because `MID` and `LEFT` return text, but you are looking into a table of numbers. You need to do something like: `=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A1,1)*1,...`

Comment: @barryhoudini, looks like we've covered both sides of the coin :).

Comment: @Doug Glancy, the problem with LEFT(A1,1)*1 is when the values are letters - that will return #VALUE! error

Comment: @barryhoudini, you are, as always, right. I read right over the "and characters" part.

Comment: `CODE(LEFT(A1,1)`will return the ASCII code for a character. However, `CODE(1)` is 49, not 1.